# How to fix "CommandNotFoundException" in PowerShell when executing python code?

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

I started a python basics course on Udemy and followed the instructions to execute the first start.py code in PowerShell.
I opened PowerShell in the same folder as the `start.py`.

```
PS C:\Users\burigs\Desktop\Desktop\Programming\Python\IntroToProgramming> python .\start.py
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python .\start.py
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Have you installed python? Try launching this with powershell in the python directory and add the path to your `start.py`, if it works, you might simply have to restart your machine.

Comment: Thank you for prompt response!
How do I find where the python directory is?
I checked 'program files' and 'users->appdata->local' but couldn't find it.

Comment: First thing you could do is type `python` in the Windows search bar and then do `open file location`. Else would be to reinstall it and write down where you install it .. Mine is in C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37

Comment: Run .\python.exe or add python.exe to your path.

Comment: [1] did you install python? it is NOT a default on windows machines. ///// [2] is it in your path statement? run  the following in the powershell ISE or console >>> `$env:Path -split ';' | Sort-Object` <<< to see a neatly sorted listing of your path.